# scraping a string and convert it into integer

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get(f"https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=web%20development&start=0")
source = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

job_posted = soup.find("div", {"id": "searchCountPages"}).text.strip()
job_posted = job_posted[10:-5].replace(",", "")
job_posted = int(job_posted)
print(job_posted)
```

I tried to convert a string into integer after scraping it from a website, when i run the program sometimes it work and some other times it doesn't!
i get this error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's | Page 1 of '
[image]

this is in yellow what i was trying to scrap

Comment: Obviously `job_posted[10:-5].replace(",", "")` doesn't do what you think it does. Print that it returns

Comment: And consider using regex to reliably get the number from that string

Comment: What is the value of `job_posted`?

Comment: @SpiritPony the value is the number in the string after i converted into integer

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and think about the logic of the code step by step. What is in `job_posted` immediately after reading it? What is in there after doing the slice? (Hint: the error message tells you explicitly.) Does it make sense to try to convert that to an integer? (Hint: obviously not; the error message told you this is not possible.) Do you understand why the slice has the result that it does? What is the actual rule you want to implement, in order to get the number?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel in the picture you can see that i scraped a text(Page 1 of 96,639 jobs) so i wanted to remove the letters and get the number of the jobs(96639) and convet it into an integer, and it works sometimes but some other times when i run it i get that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, regex is appropriate here:

```py
import re


p = re.compile(r"Page (\d*) of (\d*) jobs")


job_posted = soup.find("div", {"id": "searchCountPages"}).text.strip().replace(",", "")
page_num, page_count = map(int, p.match(job_posted).groups())
```

Note that this will error if that exact pattern isn't found.

Output:

```py
In [3]: page_num, page_count = map(int, p.match(job_posted).groups())

In [4]: page_num
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: page_count
Out[5]: 96575
```